# App Script code is so slow

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have created a script for my sheet to do the following when a certain cell is edited:

- Get the timestamp
- Get the user E-mail
- Add the text "New" in another spreadsheet.

  ```
    function WhenEdit(e){

    var currentDate = new Date();
    var triggeringSheets = new Array ("sheet1", "sheet2","sheet3");  
    var triggeredSheet =  e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
    var col = e.range.getColumn(); // triggered col
    var user = e.user.getEmail(); // who triggered the funcation
    var triggeredRanage =  e.range.rowEnd - e.range.rowStart + 1;
    var eventStart = e.range.rowStart + 1;
    var row = eventStart; //value for row
    var user = e.user.getEmail(); // who triggered the funcation

    if (triggeringSheets.indexOf(triggeredSheet) != -1) {// check the triggered sheet nae

      if(col === 7 && row >= 2) { //check the triggered col & row

          var newArr =[];
          var dateArr =[];
          var userArr=[];

          for(var i=0; i<triggeredRanage; i++){
                newArr.push(["New"]);
                dateArr.push([currentDate]);
                userArr.push([user]);
          }

          e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(eventStart,10,triggeredRanage,1).setValues(dateArr); // set time stamp
          e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(eventStart,9,triggeredRanage,1).setValues(userArr); // set user email

          var anotherSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Link");
          var secodSheet= anotherSheet.getSheetByName(triggeredSheet);
          secodSheet.getRange(eventStart,13, triggeredRanage, 1 ).setValues(newArr); // set new

          return;


      }
  ```

It's working but it takes forever to run!
What can I change to make it run faster?

Comment: There are already several questions in this site related to slow scripts. Please search this site thoroughly and https://developers.google.com/apps-script, share what you found and why it didn't meet your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script doesn't look bad. First try to reduce the execution time by reducing the calls to the Google Apps Script methods, like  `SpreadsheetApp.Range.getColumn()`, `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()`, `SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange`.

If that is not enough you might try to use the Advanced Sheets Service or your Sheets API.

---

Instead of

```
var col = e.range.getColumn(); // triggered col
```

use

```
var col = e.range.columnStart; // triggered col
```

Instead of calling `e.source.getActiveSheet()` multiple times declare a variable, i.e.

```
const sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
```

Instead of

```
var newArr =[];
var dateArr =[];
var userArr=[];

for(var i=0; i<triggeredRanage; i++){
      newArr.push(["New"]);
      dateArr.push([currentDate]);
      userArr.push([user]);
} 
e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(eventStart,10,triggeredRanage,1).setValues(dateArr); // set time stamp
e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(eventStart,9,triggeredRanage,1).setValues(userArr); // set user email
```

use

```
var newArr =[];
var dateArr =[];
var userArr=[];
var values = [];
for(var i=0; i<triggeredRanage; i++){
      newArr.push(["New"]);
      dateArr.push([currentDate]);
      userArr.push([user]);
      values.push([user,currentDate]);
} 
const sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet(); 
sheet.getRange(eventStart,10,triggeredRanage,1).setValues(values); // set user email and time stamp
```